# OR operator in match function and + operator usage

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, operators, match

```
function sumUpNumbers(inputString) {
  return (inputString.match(/\d+/g)||[]).reduce((a,b)=>a+ +b,0)
}
```

*I tried to find the answer but couldnt. I cant figure two things in this function.

The first is about [] in (inputString.match(/\d+/g)||[]). What is it doing there specifically? I saw it for the first time.If we pass "123450" as input string (inputString.match(/\d+/g)||[]) will return ["123450"] and a text like "how are you" will return [],an empty array.

My second question is about a+ +b. It adds two numbers and reduces it. If our input string is "2 apples, 12 oranges", our return value of the whole function will be 14. But how exactly without converting the string numbers i.e ["2","12"] to integers using parseInt() the function is a+ +b is adding the numbers. I wanna know about the syntax and all so I can use these concepts in my future learning.*

Comment: If you don't use the [`unary +`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) operator to coerce `b` to a Number, it will do String concatenation instead of addition.

Comment: Please, can u explain more what how "a+ +b" is working?

Comment: `a + +b` gets parsed as `a + (+b)`, `(+b)` converts `b` to a Number, `a + b` performs addition (since `b` is now an Number)

Comment: thanks and about first question ?

Comment: oh, [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) returns an array on success or null on failure. The `|| []` part is there to ensure that an array is always passed to reduce .